# Regex to remove a specific div and its content

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am using the Wordpress `automatic` plugin to autopost some content on my Wordpress site. This plugin gives me the ability to exclude any unwanted html content with a regular expression, but I don't know how to use regular expressions. My problem is I want to remove/strip a specific div element and its content by the div `class` attribute. The html content is:

```
<div class="socialize-containter" style="background-color:#fffce9; border: 2px solid #ddd;">
There is content here......
</div>
```

Could you please tell me how to remove this div?

Comment: why don't you give the content o be removed some identifying classname and then simply remove it by class?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/oR8dY9/1

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex for this task. It won't work if you have nested divs. Use DOMDocument with XPATH or something similar. You need to count opening and closing divs, that can't be done with regexps.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question didn't realized you were stuck with regexps. This is properly the nearest you will get with a regexp:
`/<div[^>]+class\s*=\s*"[^"]*socialize-containter[^"]*".*<\/div>/im`. But it will fail if you have another div in your social container!

Answer (score 0):

I assumed "clss=..." is identifying string.

```
<div class="socialize-containter".*\n.*.\n<\/div>
```

Comment: This regex will not work if the spacing differs (you should replace all spaces with `\s+`). Also it will fail if you have multiple classes in the class attribute (you should add `[^"]*` after the first `"` and before the last `"`). Why do you insist on new line characters? But the biggest issue with almost any regex pattern will be that it will stop at the first `</div>` which might not be the right tag if you have nested divs.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match the `div` tag and it's contents only if the value of class attribute is `socialize-containter`.

```
(?s)<div class="socialize-containter".*?<\/div>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oR8dY9/1)